# Finding whether the sequence is divergent

Tags: limits

Here's an interesting sequence:

$a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$

And my task is to find whether it has a $\lim$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ or not. My first strategy was analyzing this sequence. So you can prove that this sequence is decreasing (by discovering that $a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$ and this term that you are subtracting from $a_{n}$ must be less than zero), and you  can clearly see it's always positive (so it can't be divergent to $\infty$ nor $-\infty$). So intuitively, this has some $\lim$ but I can't prove it formally yet. (My task is not to find the exact $\lim$ but rather say whether it exists or not).

So then I tried to find the exact $\lim$ and my intuition told me to use Squeeze Theorem to prove it. But I'm not sure whether it's a good idea because after an hour I still haven't found anything that could help me progress further.

So, having proven that $a_{n}>0$ and $a_{n}$ is decreasing what should I do in order to prove that the limit exists (or show that it doesn't)?

Comment: If $a_n>0$, then $a_n$ is bounded below. If you already know that is decreasing... *bounded below + decreasing* should say something to you.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I forgot about one of these theorems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{n+k}=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}$$

**Another way:**

$$\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}\le \frac1n+\frac1n+\ldots+\frac1n= \frac nn=1$$

and since the sequence is clearly monotone ascending it converges.

Comment: I can't use integrals yet

Comment: @JohnZHANG , you are right. Thank you. I was hesitating between using the function $\;\frac1x\;$ between $\;1,2\;$ or the function $\;\frac1{1+x}\;$ between $\;0,1\;$ and mixed things.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

> A decreasing sequence with bounded blow is always convergent. (Also an increasing sequence with bounded sup is always convergent.